# Set div height on scroll (rubber band effect in IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

In my current Project, the expected behavior of our navbar is that it behaves like a positioned fixed navbar without using css-attributes like position and/or fixed.
I've played around with lots of ideas and finaly came up with a very simple solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;">
    <div id="nav-scroll-helper"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">Navigation</div>
</div>
<div style="float:right;height:10000px;border:1px solid blue;display:inline-block;">Content</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $("#nav-scroll-helper").animate({
        height: $(document).scrollTop()
    }, 0);
});
```

...and on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ej8hwu09/5/

The Problem is, that it works great in firefox and chrome but in IE i've noticed a rubber band effect. If you scroll down, the navbar "follows" the scroll-down instead of running parallel to the scroll event.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Navigation and content are parts of bootstraps grid layout. If i use the positioning property, the layout gets broken. I've also tried velocity to change the height attribute. Same result in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in IE. It's a performance thing. I think Chrome and Firefox do their repaints better. Maybe IE tries to repaint twice, once after the scroll happened, and then again after you've repositioned the element. So maybe it's a case of an over-eager repaint :P
The `.animate` might also add a minor delay.

If your aim is just to position the navigation in the top left you can use:

```
#nav-scroll-helper { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

This allows the browser to optimize repaints when scrolling, it wont need to redraw that element so the 'rubber band' effect will not occur.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem is: its a requirement not to use "position: fixed".

Comment: That's a strange requirement. You can always swap positioning mode. When you scroll you quickly apply the `position: fixed` rule. `#nav-scroll-helper.fixed { position: fixed; ... }` then when you want the nav to scroll you remove the `.fixed` class.

Comment: The problem is, that the navigation and content are parts of bootstraps grid layout. If i change the positioning property, i destroy the grid layout.